# Why am I unable to set an array in useEffect?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

I am learning React and trying to write an asynchronous hook. Using `setResult` inside of `useEffect` doesn't seem to work. When I tried to render the result, there was nothing, so I added some console logging to see what is going on. The setter function in the useState hook doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've been following [this video](https://youtu.be/HQq5Sod8AEk?t=898) for some guidance, and my code does not differ too much.

I have the following component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Search = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
  const [result, setResult] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(
            query
          )}&type=track`,
          {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.access_token
            }
          }
        )
        const json = await response.json()
        console.log({ json })
        console.log(
          json.tracks.items.map(item => {
            return item.id
          })
        )
        setResult(
          json.tracks.items.map(item => {
            return item.id
          })
        )
        console.log({result})
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

    if (query !== '') {
      fetchData()
    }
  }, [query])

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={search}
        placeholder='Search...'
        onChange={event => setSearch(event.target.value)}
        onKeyPress={event => {
          if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            setQuery(search)
          }
        }}
      ></input>
      <br />
      {result.map(item => (
        <h3 key={item}></h3>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

From `console.log ({ json })`, I see [the response from the server looks OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUbCI.png).

```
console.log(
    json.tracks.items.map(item => {
        return item.id
    })
)
```

[The above console output looks OK as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU2yz.png).

```
setResult(
  json.tracks.items.map(item => {
    return item.id
  })
)
console.log({result})
```

Why is [`result` empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXFmU.png)?

EDIT: Thanks Patrick and Talgat. I understand now. So, when I `console.log` outside of useEffect, I could see `result` is set correctly. I then realized I was missing a reference to `{item}` in my render:

```
{result.map(item => (
  <h3 key={item}>{item}</h3>
))}
```

Now I see the IDs rendered on the page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `setResult()` does not update the state synchronously, it posts an update that occurs in a scheduled microtick and triggers a re-render of the component with the updated `result`. The next time `const [result, setResult] = useState([])` is evaluated by the re-render, _then_ `result` will contain the updated array.

Comment: Try to `console.log(result)` outside of `useEffect`

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(()=>{
console.log(result);
},0);
```

Please try this instead using `console.log(result)`.
Setting state is not updated as soon as you insert value via setter( on your side `setResult` ).
So to do it, delay is needed.